# Insert keyframe menu does not show up

Tags: animation, interface

When I press <kbd>`I`</kbd> to activate the *Insert Keyframe Menu* (in the 3d-view/pose mode) a keyframe is created immediately instead of showing the menu.

This used to bring up the menu. I must have changed some setting but I have no idea which.

How do I get the menu back?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems like you've chosen some keying set in the timeline header.

[image: keying sets]

You can clear this by pressing the X next to the name if the selected keying set.

Answer (score 8):

One possibility, you may have unknowingly activated *Automatic Keyframe* feature and selecting a *Keying Set*. If this is the case, you need to deactivate the feature by toggling off the red "recording" button in **Timeline** window, and remove the keying set:

[image]

---

Interface for 2.8X and later will look as so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to select the object, ex. camera, if it is not selected pressing <kbd>I</kbd> doesn't work.